# How to create scaleable svg animations?

Tags: animation, svg

**Consider creating an SVG animation:** a rectangle move into the scene from left side of the svg image and move out from right side and this is a loop.

> (And i don't what to use canvas libraries or any javascript code).

---

**[1]** Is it possible to create this simple animation with any application (just like flash but with **svg** export)  (I know Adobe Illustrator let us export vectors but not sure about animating theme).

**[2]** Also as SVG is vector based i intend to make this svg animating fluid (setting the width of svg to 100% an content scale automatically) is it also possible?

---

> (I know how to do such these things using canvas libraries like snap.svg kinetic ... with bunch of js code i'm looking for some GUI App which let a graphic designer having no idea what JS is do it like Adobe Flash for example).

### Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about GUI App but fluid animations are possible. Look at the following elements: `animate`, `animateMotion`, `animateTransform`, `animateColor`.

Here are some examples and documentation:

- MDN: [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate), [`animateMotion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)
- [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement)